# Drag and Drop по расширениям

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-n-drop

У меня есть `listbox` как мне перетащить в него файлы по определённым расширениям?

**[Обновление]**
Попробовал такой способ, при перетаскивание в `listbox` дублируется путь к файлу.

```
private void listbox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

   foreach (string file in files)
   {
     if (file.EndsWith(".bin"))
     {   
        this.listbox.Items.Add(file);
     }
   }
}

private void listbox_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop, false) == true)
   {
       e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
   }
}
```

Comment: @AlexF, Я сначала попробовал ваш метод записать, у меня при перетаскивание автоматически дублируется файл, как можно пропускать копии файлов ?

Comment: @AlexF, Добавил

Comment: @AlexF, Ну когда перетаскиваю файл в listbox он мне выводит два раза путь к файлу.

Comment: @AlexF, Да, вы правы! Я вызывал его в `Form_Load` Убрал и заработало)